# Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext is 8783b5cda95bd601536a50091a11672a-0.0.1

Tags: magento

I have been try to solve above error since last three days. I already did lots of googling but none of solution is working for me. I am try to upload my extension to magentocommerce marketplace but I am stuck with last step.

In order to resolve about error I had try the following possible solution.

In my magentocommerce account key name is Samumaretiya_Invoice so I have packed my extension with this name but when I am try to upload it to magento commerce I will get the following error.

> Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename
>   without ext is 8783b5cda95bd601536a50091a11672a-0.0.1

Could you please any body around who can help me with this. if you need more information let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity. How could you say that this off-topic. Could you please keep practicing to go into details before taking any action.

Comment: @Enigmativity. After 5 days RND I got my answer. Anyway thanks for your marking off-topic

Comment: Where is the programming question? The code? The [php] tag? Have a read of what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Enigmativity. The following line clearly reflect that this question is about magento and someone asking about extension. " I am try to upload my extension to magentocommerce marketplace but I am stuck with last step."

Comment: @Enigmativity. if you don't know magento then you have not right to get into the business do your business about C#

Comment: But it is not a question about programming. It's about Magento. It's about uploading an extension. It's **not** about programming.